# How can I parse the left and right values of a string that looks like this: "5 - 8"

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript string which can contain a range. How can I get the left and the right values of this range. Note that there may be some spaces anywhere so it could look like:

```
"2-3"
"2  - 3"
" 2 - 3 "
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Hint: create many ranges and check whether the current row is in any.

Comment: You should consider using a [lexical analyzer](https://github.com/aaditmshah/lexer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this structure is persistent you can use `String.split` method to split the values by "-" character, and then if you need actual Integers - do additional parsing with `parseInt` e.g.:

```
var s = " 2 - 3 ";

var a = s.split("-")

var nL = parseInt(a[0]);

var nR = parseInt(a[1]);

alert(nL);
alert(nR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out ng-list, it allows for comma delimited lists to be entered in inputs and converted to an array. [Angularjs ngList](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angList)

Comment: Thanks. I checked this out but I am not really sure how I could use it to meet my needs.